# Facebook developer JSON format Quick reply

Tags: json, node.js, image, facebook, button

i would like to add a image to quick reply button itself.

However lets say i have 2 quick reply button, how i put 2 different image in 2 different quick reply in JSON format.

this is facebook developer documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"quick_replies":[
    {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Red",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/red.png",
        "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_RED"
    },
    {
        "content_type":"text",
        "title":"Green",
        "image_url":"http://example.com/img/green.png",
        "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_GREEN"
    }
]
```

Not tested, but that´s what i read from the developer docs.

Comment: cannot work. i using IBM watson and facebook messenger. i have a blank array in context.